# Magento 2 : How to move image to desired folder?

Tags: magento2, frontend, image-upload

I've image name and i would like to save it to my desired folder.

How to achieve this ? Any help would be appreciated.

**Update**

I am trying to implementing **Image Crop** function at frontend.

Like User will get option to get crop image option while they upload image.

For that I'm using a example. Check [Here](https://itsolutionstuff.com/post/php-jquery-ajax-crop-image-before-upload-using-croppie-pluginexample.html)

Its working for Core PHP.

I am trying to implementing this code in my controller.

```
    $data = $this->request->getParam('group_image');

    list($type, $data) = explode(';', $data);
    list(, $data)      = explode(',', $data);


    $data = base64_decode($data);
    echo $imageName = time().'.png'; exit;
```

Here `$imageName` returns **Image Name** now i want to save this image under **Pub/Media**.

PS : PHP they have used `file_put_contents('upload/'.$imageName, $data);`

IF i use `file_put_contents` its working but due to i am doing this in Module **MEQP2** standard not allow me to use this function I've to implement this in Magento way.

**Question :  What is Best Magento way to achieve this ?**

Comment: can you explain in detail what you want

Comment: @MurtuzaZabuawala, Check updated Post.

Answer (score 0):

Please write below function into your helper class and pass full image URL and image name by which u want to saved image at folder.

```
public function downloadImage($url, $image_name) {
            try {
                $download_image = $this->dir->getPath('media') . '/import';
                if (!file_exists($download_image)) {
                    mkdir($download_image, 0777, true);
                }
                /*Image saved at specific folder*/   
                $img = $download_image . '/' . $image_name;
                file_put_contents($img, file_get_contents($url));
                /*return image full path after saved at folder*/    
                return $img;
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $this->log('Error while saving image');
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Comment: I aint willing to use `file_put_contents`.

Answer (score 0):

Try with following code in your customized file

```
$uploader = $this->_objectManager->create(
            \Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\Uploader::class,
            ['fileId' => 'image']
        );

$mediaDirectory = $this->_objectManager->get(\Magento\Framework\Filesystem::class)->getDirectoryRead(DirectoryList::MEDIA);

$result = $uploader->save($mediaDirectory->getAbsolutePath());
```

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: You need to create helper class file **Image.php** at `Vender\Module\Helper\Image.php` and past below code

```
<?php
namespace Vender\Module\Helper;

use Magento\Framework\Filesystem;
use Magento\Framework\Url;
use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper;
use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;

class Image extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper {
    protected $scopeConfig;
    protected $storeManager;
    protected $messageManager;
    protected $_response;
    protected $_resourceConfig;
    protected $_responseFactory;
    protected $_url;
    protected $_filesystem;
    protected $_directory;
    protected $_imageFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager,
        \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface $response,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\Storage\WriterInterface $resourceConfig,
        \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseFactory $responseFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $url,
        \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem,
        \Magento\Framework\Image\AdapterFactory $imageFactory
    ) {
        $this->scopeConfig      = $scopeConfig;
        $this->_storeManager    = $storeManager;
        $this->messageManager   = $messageManager;
        $this->_response        = $response;
        $this->_resourceConfig  = $resourceConfig;
         $this->_responseFactory= $responseFactory;
        $this->_url             = $url;
        $this->_filesystem      = $filesystem;
        $this->_directory       = $filesystem->getDirectoryWrite(DirectoryList::MEDIA);
        $this->_imageFactory    = $imageFactory;
    }
    public function imageResize($src,$width=35,$height=35,$dir='yourdir/'){

        $absPath = $this->_filesystem->getDirectoryRead(DirectoryList::MEDIA)->getAbsolutePath().$src;

        $imageResized = $this->_filesystem->getDirectoryRead(DirectoryList::MEDIA)->getAbsolutePath($dir).
        $this->getNewDirectoryImage($src);
        $imageResize = $this->_imageFactory->create();

        $imageResize->open($absPath);
        $imageResize->backgroundColor([255, 255, 255]);
        $imageResize->constrainOnly(TRUE);
        $imageResize->keepTransparency(TRUE);
        $imageResize->keepFrame(true);
        $imageResize->keepAspectRatio(true);

        $imageResize->resize($width,$height);
        $dest = $imageResized ;
        $imageResize->save($dest);
        $resizedURL= $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA).$dir.$this->getNewDirectoryImage($src);
        return $resizedURL;

    }

    public function getNewDirectoryImage($src)
    {
        $segments = array_reverse(explode('/',$src));
        $first_dir = substr($segments[0],0,1);
        $second_dir = substr($segments[0],1,1);
        return 'cache/'.$first_dir.'/'.$second_dir.'/'.$segments[0];
    }
}
```

Step 2: Using below code you can call above **imageResize()** method from any class, block or templete.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$imgpath = $objectManager->create('Vender\Module\Helper\Image')->imageResize('IMAGE_PATH',50,50,'DIR_NAME/');
```

- $src: Add Image Path for Ex: “Your_Uploaded_Image_Folder/a/b/abc.png”
- $width: It should be number for Ex: “50”
- $height: It should be number for Ex: “50”
- $dir: Add directory name which you want to save and get resize image.